# How to structure a framework properly?

Tags: php, frameworks

I develop alone a framework with PHP 7. This framework is an all-in-one of multiple components that can be found in a Symfony project (Core of framework, ORM, template engine, unit tests, ...) but that I develop myself.

My framework is based on dependency injection, on bundle, controllers, actions.

Can you give me advice to improve structure of the framework ?

One of the most important points is the template engine (https://github.com/AlixSperoza/frash/tree/master/src/Template).

Actually, this working is a bit chaotic.

I load template passed in parameter.
I have an array of regex for each component of template engine (parts, condition, foreach, ...). I do a preg_match_all() on template with a big general regex.

I travel results of preg_match_all with a foreach. Inside foreach, i have a switch with a case for each regex of component.
(https://github.com/AlixSperoza/frash/blob/master/src/Template/Parsing/Parser.php)

Then, for each case in switch, i have a callExtension() which calls the component.
It's getting complicated when :

- There is a foreach. I do execute a new preg_match_all and regex on content of foreach in template.
- There is at least one parent template. Here again, preg_match_all and regex when template call {{ parent name_part }}.

Each component has a parent class, for parsing class that he calls. By example, for generate route, i have a component Route for principal parser, an other Route for Foreach parser and a last Route for Parent parser.

Then, the dependency injection loads all configuration files and pass them in parameters, for this instance of DI, is it a good method of working ?

Thanks.

Comment: Oooo look Ma, he is reinventing the wheel and he want us to waste our time helping

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)